# Selenium RC script for opening FireFox in private browsing mode

Tags: firefox, selenium-rc

How do I open FF in private browsing mode  and chrome in incognito mode using selenium - RC. I tried recording on a FF in private mode and saw the script its dosent collect any such parameter. 
Appreciate if some one can provide a C# code.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing much about Selenium RC, you can open Firefox in private browsing mode using [`-private` command line option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Command_Line_Options#-private). Alternatively you could set `browser.privatebrowsing.autostart` preference to `true`. I guess that at least one of the two is doable in Selenium RC.

Answer (score 0):

A work around i could find myself is to permanently put FF and Chrome in PB and Incognito respectively and run the sel scripts. It would be nice if I could do that programmatically. Getting the job done for now.